# How to get new input to generator in Python without create a new generator

Tags: python, yield

I try to write code that gets a list and generates all of this transformations by using yield statement.

The problem is when I want to get new input to generator by using send function, I continue to get the old input.

```
def permute(items):
    permutations = [x for x in itertools.permutations(items)]
    permutations.sort()
    for n in permutations:
        yield (n)

g = permute(['b','a','c'])
print(next(g)) #('a', 'b', 'c')
print(next(g)) #('a', 'c', 'b')
g.send(['e','q','c'])
print(next(g)) #('b', 'c', 'a') need to be ('c', 'e', 'q')
```

How can I empty the permutation list and repeat to sorting permutations list step without create a new generator?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment to an answer that you need to use `send`. Could you explain why you need to do that here? Is this a homework assignment, with the goal of teaching you how `send` works?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a new object of type `permute` and use it

```
import itertools
def permute(items):
    permutations = [x for x in itertools.permutations(items)]
    permutations.sort()
    for n in permutations:
        yield (n)

g = permute(['b','a','c'])
print(next(g)) #('a', 'b', 'c')
print(next(g)) #('a', 'c', 'b')

g =  permute(['e','q','c'])
print(next(g)) #('b', 'c', 'a') need to be ('c', 'e', 'q')
#I get ('c', 'e', 'q')
```