# How to get None when the iterator is empty in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I implemented a generator in Python, the problem is that I want to return "None" when the generator is empty:

```
def permute(items):
    permutations = [x for x in itertools.permutations(items)]
    permutations.sort()
    it = iter(permutations)
    while True:
        try:
            new_items = yield next(it)
            if new_items is not None:
                permutations = [x for x in itertools.permutations(new_items)]
                permutations.sort()
                it = iter(permutations)
        except StopIteration:
            return None
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
```

I get an error:

> StopIteration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966743/8591431 and then asked here, instead of following up via comments on that answer!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I don't see the same code at mentioned link. Edit: You edited your link I guess

Comment: Well the only difference is `new_items = yield next(it, None)` instead of `new_items = yield next(it)` if you look closely!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get new input to generator in Python without create a new generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966064/how-to-get-new-input-to-generator-in-python-without-create-a-new-generator)

Comment: Do you just want to yield `None` once before the generator finishes normally, or do you want it to yield `None` indefinitely such that anything that tries to run the generator to exhaustion (e.g. `list(permute('abc'))`) will loop infinitely?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `next(iter, None)`. You loop never ends. It works correctly for 6 times, and then, you start yielding `None`. That when you get the error.

Remove the `None`, so that you cause a `StopIteration` and cause the outer loop to end

Comment: I tried to move the None but I get "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration".

Comment: Actually how do I return "None" when the generator is empty with next method?

Answer (score 0):

```py
list(permute(['b', 'a', 'c']))
```

will return a list of the output of the generator.

However, your generator seem to return an infinite loop.

Comment: If I move the None, how do I return "None" when the generator is empty with next method?